# "That" tag not working AIML

Tags: design-patterns, bots, categories, aiml

i'm trying to make a bot with AIML, and on the code bellow, only de last item is recognized with an YES answer. Why did this happens?

```
<category>
<pattern> * </pattern>
<template><random>
    <li>Hi i am aviator wanna talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hello how are you what about discuss boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Well hello wanna talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hi there what abou talk of some boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hey there could we talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>What about talk of airplanes</li>
</random></template>
```

```
<category>
<pattern>YES</pattern>
    <that>Hi i am aviator wanna talk about boeing airplanes</that>
    <that>Hello how are you what about discuss boeing airplanes</that>
    <that>Well hello wanna talk about boeing airplanes</that>
    <that>Well hello wanna talk about boeing airplanes</that>
    <that>Hey there could we talk about boeing airplanes</that>
    <that>What about talk of airplanes</that>
<template>OK then, <set name = "topic">747</set> it will be!</template>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there can only be one 'that' in a pattern, not a list.

However, what you can do is set a 'topic' and then it would work as you expect. In response, do reset the topic as your task is completed.

```
<category>
<pattern> * </pattern>
<template>
<think><set name = "topic">planes</set></think>
<random>
    <li>Hi i am aviator wanna talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hello how are you what about discuss boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Well hello wanna talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hi there what abou talk of some boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>Hey there could we talk about boeing airplanes</li>
    <li>What about talk of airplanes</li>
</random></template>
</category>


<topic name="planes">

<category>
<pattern>YES</pattern>
 <template><think><set name = "topic"></set></think>OK then, <set name = "topic">747</set> it will be!</template>
</category>
</topic>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use a wildcard in your `<that>` pattern. Your second category then becomes:

```
<category>
<pattern>YES</pattern>
<that>* AIRPLANES</that>
<template>OK then, <set name = "topic">747</set> it will be!</template>
</category>
```

The * at the start of the `<that>` matches the input of YES when the AI's last response was any text ending with AIRPLANES. Also note the optional AIML convention of specifying `<pattern>` text and `<that>` text using upper case.